# Make a Customized LayoutRoot as a template for creating New layouts

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Good day, am still a beginner to Windows Phone and visual studio environment so apologies in advance. In Visual Studio, when creating a new layout we have the LayoutRoot by default. After having this LayoutRoot customized(with set rows and columns and a postioned TextBlock), is it possible to make the layout like a base template so that when one starts a new layout, it can have this customized Layout as its LayoutRoot. How can i do this or do i have to copy this values to every new layout that i intend to create. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options come to mind here.

You can make a visual studio item template for your customized page where you can easily add it to new projects. Check this tutorial on how to make item templates: [Visual Studio - How To Create Item Templates](http://tech.pro/tutorial/780/visual-studio-how-to-create-item-templates)

You can make a base page with the customized xaml and have your other pages inherit from it.

You can make user controls responsible for specific UI parts and then add these controls to pages whenever needed.